# Getting multiple data in multiple functions with callbacks Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, callback

I want multiple functions that have callbacks and this functions will return data of DB. An example:

```
getStates: function (callback) {
        try {
            dbExecution.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Table",
                function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }, function (rowCount, more, rows) {
                    if (rowCount > 0) {
                        callback(rows);
                    } else {
                        callback(null);
                    }
                });
        } catch (ex) {
            console.log(ex);
            callback(null);
        }
    }
```

But this function is only one, I have a five functions that do same but get diferent data. The "main" function:

```
router.get('/content', sessionChecker, function (req, res) {
    Module.getStates(function (data) {
        res.render('info-user', { states: data });
    });
    Module.getReligion(function (data) {
        res.render('info-user', { religions: data });
    });
});
```

How can I do to call the 5 functions with Asynchronous Javascript (States, City, Religion, etc.) without having nested the functions?

Comment: ease your work... install [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) module in node.js and use it ... few days before I was doing the same thing to obtain data from database and needed to wait for it... async is really good for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change each `get*` method to return a `Promise` (rather than using callbacks), and then you can use `Promise.all` on an array of those `Promises`. The `Promise.all` will resolves when all of the `Promises` in the array have resolved - then, you can `res.render`:

```
getStates: () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  dbExecution.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Table",
    reject,
    function(rowCount, more, rows) {
      // if rowCount is 0, do you want to reject?
      // if (rowCount === 0) reject();
      resolve(rows);
    }
  )
})
```

Then, once all the functions look like the above:

```
router.get('/content', sessionChecker, function (req, res) {
  Promise.all([
    Module.getStates(),
    Module.getReligion(),
  ]).then(([states, religions]) => {
    res.render('info-user', { states, religions });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // handle errors
  });
});
```